# Icon theme doesn't apply to Nautilus at all!

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gnome-tweak-tool, ubuntu-gnome, icon-themes

You can see that I have applied the 'Simple' icon theme in Gnome. I am using Ubuntu Gnome. And have download the tarball then extracted it into the /.icon before applying it through Gnome Tweak Tool. 
But apart from system icons , Nautilus icons fail to change
I have restarted my computer, and tried to keep the extracted folder in /usr/share/icons/ by sudo nautilus but still it doesn't work.
please Help

Answer (score 0):

I am not to sure if I understand this part right:

> But apart from system icons , Nautilus icons fail to change I have restarted my computer, and tried to keep the extracted folder in /usr/share/icons/ by sudo nautilus but still it doesn't work.

Did you actually put the `Simple`-icon-theme-folder into `/usr/share/icons/` ?!

If not move it there, using `sudo mv` [ [root privileges](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) | [move/rename](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_mv.htm)] command.

Put the icon-theme-folder (I name it `simple-icon`) on your Desktop (`~/Desktop`) and then use this command (replace `USERNAME` with yours):

```
sudo mv '/home/USERNAME/Desktop/simple-icon' '/usr/share/icons/'
```

and apply the icon-theme again, using **Gnome Tweak Tool**`

If it doesn't work, please report back.